# Deriving the fundamental solution for the Helmholtz operator in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, fourier-transform, fundamental-solution

I want to derive $G\in\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ satisfying

$$\left(\Delta+\frac{\omega^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)G=\delta,\qquad(\star)$$
where $\Delta$ is the Laplace operator, $\omega\in\mathbb{R}$ and $c>0$ is a constant.

For all $\phi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, taking the Fourier transform of $(\star)$ with respect to $x\in\mathbb{R}$ yields

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\langle\left(\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}-\xi^2\right)\mathcal{F}G,\phi\rangle=1
 \\
 \iff&\langle G,\mathcal{F}\phi\rangle=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\omega}{c}+i\varepsilon\right)^2-\xi^2},
\end{aligned}$$

where $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrarily small to avoid a singularity when we invert the Fourier transform. In particular, applying an inverse Fourier transform gives

$$\begin{aligned}
 &\langle\mathcal{F}^{-1}G,\mathcal{F}\phi\rangle=\lim_{\varepsilon\downarrow 0}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ix\cdot \xi}}{\left(\frac{\omega}{c}-i\varepsilon\right)^2-\xi^2}\,d\xi
 \\
 \iff&\langle G,\mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F}\phi\rangle=\lim_{\varepsilon\downarrow 0}\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ix\cdot \xi}-e^{-ix\cdot \xi}}{\left(\frac{\omega}{c}+i\varepsilon\right)^2-\xi^2}\,d\xi
 \\
 \iff&\langle G,\phi\rangle=\frac{ic}{2\omega}e^{i\omega|x|/c},
 \end{aligned}$$

I have three question:

> 1) Why is the $\phi$ still there? I want to have $G(x)=...$
>
> 2) I don't fully understand the final step, when the limit is taken. Could someone perhaps explain that to me?
>
> 3) Can we prove this starting with $G\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$; and what information does one need to have to solve for $G\in\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$, since fundamental solutions are generally deemed to belong to the former vector space?

Comment: Where did the line $$\langle\left(\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}-\xi^2\right)\mathcal{F}G,\phi\rangle=1$$ come from?

Comment: @WillieWong $$\mathcal{F}\left(\Delta+\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}\right)G=\left(\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}-\xi^2\right)\mathcal{F}G$$ since $\mathcal{F}(\Delta\phi)=-\xi^2\mathcal{F}\phi$

Comment: Then shouldn't $\langle (\omega/c)^2 - \xi^2) \mathcal{F}G, \phi\rangle = \langle 1, \phi\rangle =  \int \phi ~\mathrm{d}x$?

Comment: @WillieWong Why? What happens to the rest? I don't follow, to be honest.

Comment: Jason, you are doing two things at once... As @WillieWong observed, you can take the FT as a tempered distribution, and there's no necessity of pairing against a test function or Schwartz function $\phi$. So on your left-hand sides just omit the pairing angle-brackets, and omit $\phi$, and you're done.

Comment: @paulgarrett But how can you take the Fourier transform of a tempered distribution without weighting it against a Schwartz function?

Comment: In general, we might not be able to _express_ the FT of a tempered distribution directly (if it is not integration-against a classical function), but in the present situation the FT of Dirac delta is the classical function "1", and the equality of distributions implies the equality of their FT's. Yes, we are being a little optimistic that the fundamental solution will turn out to have FT which is a classical function, but/and it does. Yes, in other scenarios things can crash, but here it's fine. Strictly: this is a heuristic, then check, if  you like.